# Swapping a boolean value

Tags: c++

I have been working on a menu that is injected with a dll into call of duty modern warfare 3. As I added options to the menu, I wanted to create a void that allows me to swap a bool value.

I have tried that:

```
void swapBool(bool& xbool)
{
    if (xbool)
       !xbool;
    else if (!xbool)
        xbool;
}
```

However, it isn't working.
This is what I want it to achieve:

```
if (displayInfoBox)
    displayInfoBox = false;
else if (!displayInfoBox)
    displayInfoBox = true;
```

Because of that many bools and many more coming i wanted to create a void...

```
                if (offHostScroll == 0)
                {
                    if (rgbEffects)
                        rgbEffects = false;
                    else if (!rgbEffects)
                        rgbEffects = true;
                }
                else if (offHostScroll == 1)
                {
                    if (rgbMenu)
                        rgbMenu = false;
                    else if (!rgbMenu)
                        rgbMenu = true;
                }
                else if (offHostScroll == 2)
                {
                    if (rgbBakcground)
                        rgbBakcground = false;
                    else if (!rgbBakcground)
                        rgbBakcground = true;
                }
                else if (offHostScroll == 3)
                {
                    if (rgbMaps)
                        rgbMaps = false;
                    else if (!rgbMaps)
                        rgbMaps = true;
                }
                else if (offHostScroll == 4)
                {
                    if (rgbInGameIcons)
                        rgbInGameIcons = false;
                    else if (!rgbInGameIcons)
                        rgbInGameIcons = true;
                }
                else if (offHostScroll == 5)
                {
                    swapBool(displayInfoBox);
                    /*if (displayInfoBox)
                        displayInfoBox = false;
                    else if (!displayInfoBox)
                        displayInfoBox = true;*/
                }
```

Comment: you can just simply do the `boolName = !boolName`. that will be more clear. if you add a function, the compiler might just optimize it to be inline anyway.

Comment: I didn't know you can invert it like that. I understood your first answer wrong. It is working now thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
displayInfoBox = !displayInfoBox;
```

or

```
xbool = !xbool;
```

`!` by itself does not change the value of the variable, it just creates a new value by negating it, so you have to reassign it.

You also will have to make `swapBool` pass `xbool` by reference.

```
void swapBool(bool& xbool);
```

Comment: The thing is every time I select the option the value needs to be swapped. Lets say I need to toggle it.

Comment: @DeathRGH this will toggle it.

Comment: @DeathRGH its a combination of both.

Comment: Didn't work. Let me explain my situation a little better:

Comment: Im currently toggeling it like this:
`else if (offHostScroll == 5)
     {
      if (displayInfoBox)
       displayInfoBox = false;
      else if (!displayInfoBox)
       displayInfoBox = true;
     }`

but i want it to be re-usable for other bool's which is why i want to create a void

`else if (offHostScroll == 5)
     {
      swapBool(displayInfoBox);
     }`

Comment: @DeathRGH please edit your question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: I added more info to my question.